# Usage of negative lookahead causes no matches at all

Tags: regex

I have a regex `^\/pref1\/pref2\/v.+\/(search)(\/.*)?$` it is matching for instance `/pref1/pref2/v1/search/suf1/suf2`.

But I want it to match anything that doesn't contain word `search` in that place. To achieve that I have modified regex by adding negative lookahead:

`^\/pref1\/pref2\/v.+\/(?!search)(\/.*)?$`

but then this for instance doesn't match:

`/pref1/pref2/v1/somethingElse/suf1/suf2`
but it should as `somethingElse` not equals `search`. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\/pref1\/pref2\/v[^\/]+\/(?!search(?:\/|$))[^\/]+(\/.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KyUH9q/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\/pref1\/pref2\/v` - a `/pref1/pref2/v` string
- `[^\/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(?!search(?:\/|$))` - immediately to the right, there cannot be `search` string followed with `/` or end of string
- `[^\/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
- `(\/.*)?` - an optional capturing group matching a `/` char and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why do I need to follor ?!search by `(?:\/|$)` ?

Comment: @Yoda You need to make sure `search` is followed with `/` or end of string, else you would fail `searching`, etc. See my regex fiddle (demo).

Comment: I thought that this `(\/.*)?` was enough as I wanted to express that I am expecting nothing or `/` followed by anything. I know that I am wrong, just trying to grasp why.

Comment: @Yoda That is not enough, the condition must be defined for the lookahead pattern.